# How to reset a Sharepoint site to its initial state?

Tags: sharepoint-online, restore

I'm using Sharepoint Online for a client and I have very little understanding of how Sharepoint works. I apparently have completely broken the site. After two days of hard work, most of the site works again, but some pages are still unavailable: lots of configuration pages just crash when I access them. It's impossible to change the site's theme, it's impossible to use the 'Add page' feature, the homepage is broken and can't be set/fixed... it's pretty catastrophic.

The sanity check from the Sharepoint settings page shows all green, but all these problems are still happening.

These issues are happening on the site that is at the root of the site collection, so I don't have the option of deleting the site. I need a way to reset it from scratch.
I do not care if it ends up destroying the site subsites as well. If I could just go back to a 'blank' account like it was the first time I accessed Sharepoint Online, it'd be perfect. If I can keep the subsites though, it'd be even better.

Comment: If you don't mind deleting the subsites, why not delete and recreate the site collection in the SharePoint admin center?

Comment: I'm doing this on a client's sharepoint online thingy, and apparently he doesn't want us to have access to the admin center. And we can't ask the client either because deleting a site collection is too 'complex'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of options

1. If it's your master page that is screwed up, try defaulting it to the v4.master and check the links. You can do this by SharePoint designer.
2. If that doesn't work, try resetting the root site to its site definition from SharePoint designer.
3. Or else if your account has MSFT support, raise a ticket and they can restore the site to its previous version based on their recent backup.

Comment: I'm afraid I removed the SitePages folder myself. It doesn't seem to be possible to reset files that were removed to the site's definition. It seems my last resort is getting support from Microsoft :( ! Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 2):

Firstly there is no way to reset a site in the way you are referring to or need to sadly. Deleting the Site Collection would be the most efficient way to start again or reset your work but as you have said this is not possible.

I would start by troubleshooting your work. It is important to understand the customisations you have made. Can you share more information with us such as where you were working and what changes you were making? What types of errors are you receiving?

Have you tried accessing the web part maintenance page? To do this browse to a page that is not working and then type onto the end of the URL ?contents=1 (for example http://contoso.sharepoint.com/default.aspx?content=1). From this page you will be able to remove or reset web parts that are on the page. If you were modifying web parts yo will be able to remove them one-by-one to see if this fixes the page(s).

You could also try disabling any features if you were using such as the publishing feature. Once you have disabled them you could try enabling them again to see if this resolves things. Again do this one-by-one to help you identify which feature might be at fault.

The Site Pages library should be in the Recycle Bin and therefore you should be able to restore it. From the site click on the settings menu (cog/gear icon) in the top right and select site contents. From this page you'll see a link to the recycle bin. Select the Site Pages library and hit restore.

Microsoft will not be able to support you or do anything if you are not an administrator.